# How to remove escape extra slash in java properties

Tags: java, escaping

I am using the following to write some values to a .properties file.
this code works with one small problem the value that gets written is like this

```
C\:/MyDir/MyDir2/Downloads/SomeOrder.txt
```

With an extra slash, this does not work. For the life of me I can't get rid of the extra slash. I have tried URLEncode.encode but no go.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "extra slash"? Please clarify how exactly your output should look like; and of course: provide the code that does the writing. As of now, your question does not contain the information we would need to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's fine. That's how it's *meant* to be written to the properties file.

From the [`Properties.store`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store-java.io.Writer-java.lang.String-) documentation:

> The key and element characters #, !, =, and : are written with a preceding backslash to ensure that they are properly loaded.

The code that *reads* the value from the properties file will unescape it appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response, I will try it.

Comment: Thanks that worked! the format of it was causing a bit of consternation.